# NSMutableArray sorting -- passing parameter to comparitor block

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I need to sort the array of string and want to access `viewController` property in the comparator block. So, Planning to pass `ViewController` object to comparator block. How to pass parameter to comparator block ?

Here is the Code.

Since comparator logic is lengthy and sorting is used many places, I can't expand comparatorBlock in the declaration.

```
sortedArray = [NsMutableArray arrayWithArray:[unsortedArray sortedArrayWithOptions:0 usingComparator:comparatorBlock]];
```

Comment: You simply reference the view controller object reference in the block.  I don't see the complication.

Comment: I tried to access viewcontroller in the block using "self". getting compilation error. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: You need to show the code, or some representative example of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the block in a method of the view controller, then it should be able to access `self`.

If you can't do that, you can create a function that returns the block and captures the view controller as a function argument:

```
static NSComparator blockWithViewController(UIViewController *viewController) {
    return ^NSComparisonResult (id object1, id object2) {
        NSLog(@"view controller is %@", viewController);
        return NSOrderedSame;
    };
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[unsortedArray sortedArrayWithOptions:0 usingComparator:blockWithViewController(viewController)] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Why the `NSMutableArray arrayWithArray` bit?

Comment: I copied it from the question without thinking too hard about it. I would probably use `mutableCopy` instead. I s'pose I should clean that up...

Answer (score 0):

[altom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25055518/4515489) gave me a build error, "Returning block that lives on the local stack".

That can be resolved by wrapping the block in Block_copy() as in [nielsbot's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419130).

This example is using MRR rather than ARC, so an autorelease was added.

```
static NSComparator blockWithViewController(UIViewController *viewController) {
    return [Block_copy(^NSComparisonResult (id object1, id object2) {
        NSLog(@"view controller is %@", viewController);
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }) autorelease];
}
```